# Why can't I flatMap a Try?

Tags: scala

Given

```
val strings = Set("Hi", "there", "friend")
def numberOfCharsDiv2(s: String) = scala.util.Try { 
  if (s.length % 2 == 0) s.length / 2 else throw new RuntimeException("grr") 
}
```

Why can't I flatMap away the Try resulting from the method call? i.e.

```
strings.flatMap(numberOfCharsDiv2)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.util.Try[Int]
 required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
              strings.flatMap(numberOfCharsDiv2)
```

or

```
for {
  s <- strings
  n <- numberOfCharsDiv2(s)
} yield n
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.util.Try[Int]
 required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
            n <- numberOfCharsDiv2(s)
```

However if I use Option instead of Try there's no problem.

```
def numberOfCharsDiv2(s: String) = if (s.length % 2 == 0) 
  Some(s.length / 2) else None
strings.flatMap(numberOfCharsDiv2) # =>  Set(1, 3)
```

What's the rationale behind not allowing flatMap on Try?

Comment: With `Option` it works only because there is an implicit conversion `Option[A] => Iterable[A]`. I'd rather ask what is the rationale behind this conversion.

Comment: So that we can conceive of an `Option` as a list bounded to max 1 size. Super handy, nay?

Comment: I use the `Option[A] => Iterable[A]` implicit conversion all the time. I think it's quite useful to think of an option as a 0-to-1 container.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's look at the signature of `flatMap`.

```
def flatMap[B](f: (A) => GenTraversableOnce[B]): Set[B]
```

Your `numberOfCharsDiv2` is seen as `String => Try[Int]`. `Try` is not a subclass of `GenTraversableOnce` and that is why you get the error. You don't strictly need a function that gives a `Set` only because you use `flatMap` on a `Set`. The function basically has to return any kind of collection.

So why does it work with `Option`? `Option` is also not a subclass of `GenTraversableOnce`, but there exists an implicit conversion inside the `Option` companion object, that transforms it into a `List`.

```
implicit def option2Iterable[A](xo: Option[A]): Iterable[A] = xo.toList
```

Then one question remains. Why not have an implicit conversion for `Try` as well? Because you will probably not get what you want.

`flatMap` can be seen as a `map` followed by a `flatten`.

Imagine you have a `List[Option[Int]]` like `List(Some(1), None, Some(2))`. Then `flatten` will give you `List(1,2)` of type `List[Int]`.

Now look at an example with `Try`. `List(Success(1), Failure(exception), Success(2))` of type `List[Try[Int]]`.

How will flatten work with the failure now?

- Should it disappear like `None`? Then why not work directly with `Option`?
- Should it be included in the result? Then it would be `List(1, exception, 2)`. The problem here is that the type is `List[Any]`, because you have to find a common super class for `Int` and `Throwable`. You lose the type.

These should be reasons why there isn't an implicit conversion. Of course you are free to define one yourself, if you accept the above consequences.

Comment: Nice answer, especially the part on the types, `None` holds no value and they can easily and safely be removed, `Failures` instead hold a value which has meaning and so it cannot (and shouldn't) be removed, but keeping them would mean that if there where a conversion you would end up with list of `Any` loosing type information and safety, I guess it's a pretty strong argument.

Comment: I understand your answer, but I think it's not the right design on behalf of the std lib. The datatype is `Try[A]`, hence I only care about the `A`s. I should be able to flatten away the `Try`, discarding the `Failure` values - just as per the `Option` semantics.

Comment: Yes, `Try` has only one generic parameter. But only because the type for `Failure` is already set to `Throwable` and needs no further specification. You use `Try` when you also care about the exceptions. If you don't: use `Option` from the start or use the `toOption` method on your `Try`. For your case: `strings.flatMap(numberOfCharsDiv2(_).toOption)`

Comment: +1, but arguably `Try` is conceptually a specialisation of `Either`. Where `Either` only treated the right value as important by convention, `Try` should be enforcing this. For me, allowing flattening away of Failures is not just a convenience but an important design decision that should have been made.

Comment: I agree that it is debatable.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that in your example, you're not flatmapping over Try. The flatmap you are doing is over Set.

Flatmap over Set takes a Set[A], and a function from A to Set[B]. As Kigyo points out in his comment below this isn't the actual type signature of flatmap on Set in Scala, but the general form of flat map is:

`M[A] => (A => M[B]) => M[B]`

That is, it takes some higher-kinded type, along with a function that operates on elements of the type in that higher-kinded type, and it gives you back the same higher-kinded type with the mapped elements.

In your case, this means that for each element of your Set, flatmap expects a call to a function that takes a String, and returns a Set of some type B which could be String (or could be anything else).

Your function

```
numberOfCharsDiv2(s: String)
```

correctly takes a String, but incorrectly returns a Try, rather then another Set as flatmap requires.

Your code would work if you used 'map', as that allows you to take some structure - in this case Set and run a function over each element transforming it from an A to a B without the function's return type conforming to the enclosing structure i.e. returning a Set

`strings.map(numberOfCharsDiv2)`

`res2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[scala.util.Try[Int]] = Set(Success(1), Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: grr), Success(3))`

Comment: `flatMap` over `Set[A]` needs a function from `A => GenTraversableOnce[B]`. It does not need to be a `Set[B]`.

Comment: Hi Kigyo. Yes I realise that is the case in this specific instance, I was trying to talk more about the general case of flatmap, or bind in haskell, the structure of which is: (M[A])(A => M[B]): M[B].

Comment: Unfortunately this answers a misinterpreted question.

Answer (score 2):

It is a Monad in Scala 2.11:

```
scala> import scala.util._ 
import scala.util._

scala> val x: Try[String] = Success[String]("abc")
x: scala.util.Try[String] = Success(abc)

scala> val y: Try[String] = Failure[String](new Exception("oops"))
y: scala.util.Try[String] = Failure(java.lang.Exception: oops)

scala> val z = Try(x)
z: scala.util.Try[scala.util.Try[String]] = Success(Success(abc))

scala> val t = Try(y)
t: scala.util.Try[scala.util.Try[String]] = Success(Failure(java.lang.Exception: oops))

scala> z.flatten
res2: scala.util.Try[String] = Success(abc)

scala> t.flatten
res3: scala.util.Try[String] = 
Failure(java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: oops)
```

Answer (score 2):

Kigyo explains well why Scala does not do this implicitly. To put it simply, Scala does not want to automatically throw away the exception that is preserved in a Try.

Scala does provide a simple way to explicitly translate a Try into an Option though. This is how you can use a Try in a flatmap:

```
strings.flatMap(numberOfCharsDiv2(_).toOption)
```